# Toolbar disappearing when scrolling

Tags: uinavigationbar

I have a table view controller in my app. I have many table view cells in it. When I scroll down in the table view, the toolbar/navigation bar disappears. When I scroll back to the top of the screen, it is visible again. Please tell me how to have the toolbar/navigation bar visible at all times.
[image]

[image]

Comment: too vague. post your code please.

Comment: I dont have any code. Its a view based application.

Comment: Post some screenshots, then. Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes I am using storyboards

Comment: It's pretty odd. This shouldn't happen. How did you put this together? Did you use the viewcontroller widget in storyboards?

Comment: I added a table view controller to the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

refer below link, it may help you. It's an example of simple navigation controller with UITableView:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews